# How to align divs to look like a skype chat window?

Tags: html, css

This is my first question here at Stack overflow and I hope that I have done everything right.

I'm trying to position some divs to appear in the same way as a Skype chat window. There are multiple ways of align three divs, left, center right or two div's to the left, but I haven't found a way of align two divs to the right, side by side. Especially not if one of them doesn't have a fixed size.

I have been able to position the incoming user's profile pic, chat bubble and time stamp but I haven't found a way of positioning the outgoing dito.

I also admit that the code is quite messy right now because of all my attempts to get it right so i would really appreciate some help here that could put me on the right track.

This chat window is an example of what I want to achive:
[Skype chat window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyrLC.png)

This is the html:

Incoming messages:

```
<div class="skype-parent">

<img class="skype-in-avatar" src="users_avatar.jpg alt="" />

<div class="skype-in-message">
This is the incoming text.
</div>

<div class="skype-timestamp">
08:42
</div>
</div>
```

Outgoing messages:

```
<div class="skype-parent">

<div class="skype-out-message">
This is the outgoing text.
</div>

<div class="skype-timestamp">
08:56</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Css for parent div (works!):

```
div.skype-parent {
    text-align:         left;
    margin-top:         0.2em;
    margin-bottom:      0.2em;
    clear:              both; }
```

Css for timestamp div (works!):

```
div.skype-timestamp {
    text-align:         center;
    margin-top:         0.5em;
    float:              right; }
```

Css for incoming messages (works!):

```
img.skype-in-avatar {
    float:              left;
    width:              30px; 
    height:             30px;
    margin-left:        0.5em;
    margin-right:       0.5em;
    border-radius:      1.5em;      }


div.skype-in-message {
    max-width:          75%;
    background-color:   #c7edfc;
    padding:            0.5em;
    border-radius:      10px;
    display:            inline-block;
    vertical-align:     bottom; }
```

CSS for outgoing messages (not working):

```
div.skype-out-message {
    max-width:          75%;
    background-color:   #e5f7fd;
    padding:            0.5em;
    border-radius:      10px; }
```

So, what I need help with here is the positioning code for this outgoing message. As seen in the example the chat bubble are positioned to the right, but still to the left of the timestamp.

Comment: Can you show everything in a single snippet please?

Comment: You forgot a quote here: `src="users_avatar.jpg alt=""` after `.jpg`.

Comment: There an orphaned `</p>`. Should be `</div>` or completely removed.

Comment: Also please have a look at the **[tour]** and **[ask]** pages.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. Now I have something to work with. I apologize for the small errors and for not put it all together in one snippet. I will follow your advise and read the tour and the How Ask pages to be better prepared the next time I have to ask something. I will click the tick button later when I have tested both the solutions to my question. Thanks again for your quick and helpful reply. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```css
.skype-parent{
  font:         14px/1.23 sans-serif;
  display:      table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width:        100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 10px;
}

/* ROWS */

.message{
  display: table-row;
}

/* ALL CELLS */

.message > *{
  position:   relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:    table-cell;
}
.message img{
  border-radius:  50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* IMAGE CELL & TIME CELL */

.message > div:nth-child(1),
.message > div:nth-child(3){
  width:      52px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:  12px;
  color:      #AFCBD8;
}

/* MESSAGE CELLS */

.message p {
  color:      #6E767C;
  border-radius:4px;
  padding: 12px 14px;
  margin: 0 36px 0 0;
  background: #c7edfc;
}
.message.user p {
  margin: 0 0 0 36px;
  background: #e5f7fd;
}

/* ARROWS */

.message > div:nth-child(2):after {
  position:   absolute;
  content:    "";
  width:      8px;
  height:     8px;
  background: #c7edfc;
  left:       0;
  top:        18px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  transform:  rotate(45deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.message.user > div:nth-child(2):after {
  left:       100%;
  background: #e5f7fd;
}
```

```html
<div class="skype-parent">

  <div class="message">
    <div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZIkv.jpg?s=32&g=1"></div>
    <div><p>It's easy!</p></div>
    <div>08:40</div>
  </div>

  <div class="message user">
    <div></div>
    <div><p>Really?</p></div>
    <div>08:42</div>
  </div>

  <div class="message">
    <div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZIkv.jpg?s=32&g=1"></div>
    <div><p>Well...</p></div>
    <div>08:42</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

***To recap:*** imagine your chat window as a *table* grid:

[image]

you see ROWS and three cells per row.
Cool, now, color the `<p>` of the .message DIV (cells), add margin-left for the incoming message, and margin-right for the other one.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I haven't time to test it right now but I will do it tonight or tomorrow. Your code is a lot more clean than mine and I will try to understand it in depth later. :)